# How to echo out to user if date is equal to their birthday?

Tags: php, date, if-statement

so for one of my school assignments I've been having troubles echoing out to the user after they have inputed their birthday. I have to echo out to the user 2 ways. 1) if the date equals their birthday they get a nice message, and 2) if the date does NOT equal their birthday then they get a different message.

For some reason my if statement isn't working... Help?

Here's the if statement........

```
<?php    

//if statement for birthday
$month = $_POST['month'];
$year = $_POST['year'];
$day = $_POST['day'];

$date = $year ."-". $month ."-".$day;

$date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($date));

if(date('m-d') == date('m-d', $date)) {
    // today is users birthday. show any message you want here.
    echo "<p>Happy Birthday $firstname!</p>\n";
 } else {
    echo "<p>You were born $date.</p>\n";
 }

?>
```

And... Here's the drop down lists....

```
<?php
            $months = array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");

            //1950 is standard year thing for most websites I've noticed
            $yearFrom = 1950; // The first year included in the drop-down for years


            // $yearFrom = date("Y")-80; 
            // Using this line instead, gives a dynamic range of years, always 80 years
            // Echo out all years via a for-loop
            //<select> IS the dropdown box
            echo "<select name=\"year\" id=\"year\">";
            //less than or equal to current year
            for ($yearFrom; $yearFrom <= date("Y"); $yearFrom++) {
                    // Each $yearFrom represents a year, always incremented by 1 year
                    //echos out every year that we put present.......
                    echo "<option value=\"$yearFrom\">$yearFrom</option>";
            }
            echo "</select>";


            // Echo out all months from the array $months
            echo "<select name=\"month\" id=\"month\">";
            foreach($months as $key=>$value) {
                    // $key is the index of the array, starting at 0
                    $numericMonth = $key + 1;
                    echo "<option value=\"$numericMonth\">$value</option>";
            }
            echo "</select>";


            // Echo out all days (1-31) via a for-loop
            echo "<select name=\"day\" id=\"day\">";
            for ($i=1; $i <= 31; $i++) {
                    // Each $i represents a numeric value of days, from 1-31
                    echo "<option value=\"$i\">$i</option>";
            }
            echo "</select>";

            ?>
```

So... Thats what I have.. All ideas and assistance is greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: Are you getting an error message or is the output not what you are expecting?

Comment: @Lima no errors. It's outputting the wrong message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**See demo [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/63e80520c152b89250ff887cecc9f175d59750fe)**

To use `strtotime()` and get exact results, first set your date and time zone.

Try this,

```
date_default_timezone_set ('Asia/Kolkata');// this leni should be added to use strtotime()

$date = "date from post value";
if (date('m-d', strtotime($date)) == date('m-d')) {
    echo "<p>Happy Birthday $firstname!</p>\n";
} else {
    echo "<p>You were born $date.</p>\n";
}
```

**See demo [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/63e80520c152b89250ff887cecc9f175d59750fe)**

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
$date = "Your boirthday date";
 $dob = date('d-m',strtotime($date));//
 $today = date('d-m');
if($dob == $today)
{

    $todayBirthday = "Bithday today";


}else{
    $noTodayBirthday = "<h2 class='birthdaytoday'>No Birthday </h2>";

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I modified @Ricky version slightly

```
    $date = $_POST['year'] ."-". $_POST['month'] ."-".$_POST['day'];
    $dob = date('d-m',strtotime($date));
    $today = date('d-m');
    if($dob == $today)
    {
       echo "<p>Happy Birthday $firstname!</p>\n";
    } else 
    {
       echo "<p>You were born $date.</p>\n";
    }
```